# adding custom CSS to django admin forms

Tags: python, css, django, django-admin

I'm trying to style a form in django admin. I created a file to extend the base admin page with `myApp/templates/admin/base_site.html` and I'm calling in a new css file with:

```
{% extends 'admin/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block branding %}

{% block extrastyle %}

  <link rel='stylesheet' href='{% static 'css/admin.css' %}'>
{% endblock %}

{% endblock %}
```

I added a static directory and file at `myApp/static/admin/css/admin.css`. Since the admin app has already took control of URIs like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/admin/css/base.css` my app can't find `static/css/base.css` because it expects my `admin.css` to be in `venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css`.  I want to extend the base css (add to it), not necessarily completely override it.

I'm guessing the answer is to edit `settings.py` to tell it to look at `myApp/static` but I'm not sure how. The relevant `settings.py` lines are:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static/'),
]

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Would the [`Media` class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/media/) work?